# Flask socketio split app.py: AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'wsgi_app'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-socketio

I am using flask socketio for a web socket project and I splited the views using flask `blueprint`. The issue is that the socketIO is not working correctly and am getting the following error:

```
/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 31, in __init__
    flask_app.wsgi_app,
AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'wsgi_app'
```

My project structure is a follows:

```
|-- App
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- app.py
|   |-- templates
|   |   |-- main.html
|   |   |-- pymeetups.html
|   -- views
|       |-- __init__.py
|       | --- test.py
|-- __init__.py
|-- run.py
```

run.py:

```
from gevent import monkey
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
monkey.patch_all()

from App.views import test
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='app/templates')
app.register_blueprint(test.app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, "0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

test.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
app = Blueprint('app', __name__)

socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/dd')
def ws_conn():
    print("connect")
    socketio.emit('msg', {'count': 1}, namespace='/dd')


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace="/dd")
def ws_disconn():
    print("disconnect")
```

The issue comes from the test.py file with the statement:

```
app = Blueprint('app', __name__)

socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

If dont use flask blueprint and combine all into one single file it works perfectly:

app.py:

```
from gevent import monkey
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
monkey.patch_all()


app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('main.html')



@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/dd')
def ws_conn():
    socketio.emit('msg', {'count': 1}, namespace='/dd')


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/dd')
def ws_disconn():
    print("Disconnected")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, "0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

How can i split the routes as i expect my application to have lots of functions and it is difficult to manage all function into a single file.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Blueprint object works similarly to a Flask application object, but
>   it is not actually an application.

Here in your code, you are trying to register an extension `SocketIO(blueprint)` with an blueprint. It should be the application extension not the blueprint extension. Something like this should work for you:

```
# For example my app structure like this
- app/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    main/
       __init__.py
       views.py
```

---

```
#app/app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

from main import main

app.register_blueprint(main, url_prefix='/main')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)

#app/main/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from . import views

#app/main/views.py
from . import main
from app import socketio

@main.route('/')
def index():
        return "Hello"

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/dd')
def ws_conn():
    socketio.emit('msg', {'count': 1}, namespace='/dd')

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/dd')
def ws_disconn():
    print('Disconnected')
```

Comment: The structure you specified shows no errors related to the `blueprint` but the socketio is not working. No socket is emitted.

Comment: Miguel Gringberg: The following example application demonstrates how to structure a larger app that has blueprints:

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat